# how to destructure this.props react js

Tags: react.js, reactive-programming

I'm trying to create a component that receives an array, this component is going to show a list with props data

```
const Mesas = [{
      id: 1,
      valor: 500,
      produtos:['COCA COLA', 'FANTA']
    },{
      id: 2,
      valor: 100,
      produtos:['PRATO1', 'PRATO2']
    }]
const App = () => {
    return (<ListaMesas mesas = {{...Mesas}} />)
}
```

The component:

```
class mesas extends Component {
    render(){
        const mesas = [this.props.mesas]
        mesas.map(function(item){
           return(
               <div key ={item.id}>
                   <text>{item.id}</text>
               </div>
           )
        })
        return(
            <div>  
                {mesas}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *really* need to destructure at all, you can simply use props directly if you like

```
this.props.mesas.map(item => ...
```

example

```
class Mesas extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.mesas.map(function(item) {
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <text>{item.id}</text>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

***but*** if you did want/need to destructure your props, then the correct pattern is

```
const { mesas } = this.props;
```

example

```
class Mesas extends Component {
  render() {
    const { mesas } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {mesas.map(function(item) {
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <text>{item.id}</text>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

At this point though there isn't much use in using a class-based component; no component lifecycle functions are used, no constructor, etc... a simpler functional component will do the job ***and*** allow you to destructure the props right in the function signature (you can even do this with the array::map callback).

```
const Mesas = ({ mesas }) => (
  <div>
    {mesas.map(({ id }) => (
      <div key={id}>
        <text>{id}</text>
      </div>
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to refactor your problem is to use React programming pattern: a stateful, parent component passes down a prop to a stateless, child component. So, you don't ever need to declare `mesas` as a class, it is just a functional component because we dividing components into presentational components and container components.
But, I didn't get about the App's state, if you plan to use external storage fine, but if you need to manage the local state, just insert the `mesas` in your `App` under constructor. However, abstracting, based on your code, my  refactoring:

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';

const mesas = [{
      id: 1,
      valor: 500,
      produtos:['COCA COLA', 'FANTA']
    },{
      id: 2,
      valor: 100,
      produtos:['PRATO1', 'PRATO2']
    }]
const App = () => {
    return (<ListaMesas mesas = {mesas} />)
}
```

```
// Mesas.js
import React from 'react';

export const mesas = ({ mesas }) => {
    const mesasList = mesas.map((mesa) => {
        <div key={mesa.id}>
            <text>{mesa.id}</text>
        </div>
    })
    return (
        <div>
            {mesasList}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this will be very useful